# Windows 10 HDMI Saturation until full screen video played

Tags: windows-10, video, hdmi

This is driving me insane, I have my computer connected to an HD TV via a HDMI.  When I change the TV’s input the computer the screen has saturated colours (Washed Out colours).  The only thing that seems to fix it is playing a video at full screen (YouTube, Netflix, Twitch, Mixer, GiantBomb etc..).

Before I get down voted and told to set my output dynamic range to Full instead of limited like as [stated here](https://www.howtogeek.com/285277/how-to-avoid-washed-out-colors-when-using-hdmi-on-your-pc/) I have done that and confirm that option doesn’t change after reboot.  Also happens if there is multiple monitors or just connected to the TV.

This is running on a GTX 1080 (latest and multiple different drivers), Windows 10 and a Sony Bravia KDL-55W802A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally figured it out.  Turns out my TV was switching to “GameMode” and that was doing the saturation.  Forced my HDMI input to “General” and I have been good.